# Weird behavior with class attribute, __iadd__ (+=) and numpy.random.randn()

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have been modelling a stochastic process with Python and Numpy and witnessing weird behavior with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class Example( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x = 0

    def add_random( self ):
        self.x += np.random.randn(1)
        return self.x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = Example()
    state = []
    for x in range(10):
        state.append( example.add_random() )
    print state
```

This will return an array of 10 identical random numbers as opposed to 10 different random numbers as expected. Eliminating the `object.__iadd__` operator and/or replacing `np.random.randn(.)` with a constant will solve the issue. Anybody has an idea what is the root of this?

Comment: WarrenWeckesser explained the root of your problem, but fundamentally, using `numpy` to do this is *incredibly inefficient*. You create array-objects each time, which has a significant overhead. Instead, use `random.gauss`

Comment: Note, if you wanted to do this efficiently using `numpy` then just use `np.random.randn(10).cumsum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the array `self.x` by reference, so you have 10 pointers to the same array. Every time the array is modified, all ten pointers point to the same modified version.

If you want to return separate copies of the array each time, you could `return self.x.copy()` in the `add_random` function.

An alternative fix would be to replace `np.random.rand(1)` with `np.random.rand()` so `self.x` would remain a scalar rather than being up-cast to an array.

Comment: Thanks – I changed "integer" to "scalar" to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4):

`np.random.randn(1)` returns an array containing a single element:

```
In [27]: np.random.randn(1)
Out[27]: array([-1.90409169])
```

The first time this line is executed

```
self.x += np.random.randn(1)
```

`self.x`--initially a Python integer--is replaced by a numpy array.  Subsequent execution of that line *modifies `x` in-place*, because that's how numpy arrays implement in-place addition.  So `return self.x` always returns the *same* array.  Thus the list that you create in the main section is a list containing the same object repeated 10 times.

One way to fix this is to use `np.random.randn()` instead of `np.random.randn(1)`.  `np.random.randn()` returns a scalar, so the assignment `self.x += np.random.randn(1)` creates a new `self.x` object each time it is executed.